# Product coproduct sign

Tags: math-mode

I want to have a product sign analogously to `$A \amalg B$`. I tried `$A \Pi B$`, but as `$\Pi$` isn't a binary operator, this does not look that good.

Can you help me?

Comment: You can try drawing the symbol at [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html); if it can find a match, it will tell you the command for the symbol and which package it's loaded with.

Comment: `\coprod`, `\prod`, `\amalg`, `\Pi`. You can find those with my classifier [write-math.com](http://write-math.com)

Answer (score 19):

Use `\mathbin` to fix the spacing issue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*\productop{\mathbin{\Pi}}

\begin{document}
\[ a \amalg b \qquad a \productop b\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 18):

Another solution is to rotate 180° the symbol `\amalg` (requires `graphicx`) to get exactly the same symbol upside down:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\invamalg}{\mathbin{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\amalg$}}}

\begin{document}
\[ A \amalg B \qquad A \invamalg B\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

To get a size changing symbol you can load the `amsmath` package and modify the `\newcommand` line as follows (thanks to egreg for the suggestion):

```
\newcommand{\invamalg}{\mathbin{\text{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\amalg$}}}}
```

In this way you can use the new defined command even in subscripts and superscripts. The following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\invamalg}{\mathbin{\text{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\amalg$}}}}

\begin{document}

\[
 A \invamalg B_{A \invamalg B_{A \invamalg B}}
\]

\[
 A \amalg B_{A \amalg B_{A \amalg B}}
\]

\end{document}
```

gives the result:

[image]

Comment: `\amalg` is slightly different from a reversed `\Pi`. You can get a size changing symbol by loading `amsmath` and putting `\rotatebox[...]{180}{...}` inside `\text`.

Comment: With `\mathchoice{\text{...}}` you're typesetting the symbol sixteen times instead of the four with the `\text` method and the result is exactly the same (`\text` already does `\mathchoice` by itself). There's no need to load `\mathtools` in order to have `\mathchoice`, which is a primitive of TeX.

Comment: @egreg I've deleted that solution. Thanks for pointing it out.